# Returning to a previous window

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI using Qt creator for my Thesis. I am working on the functions of the buttons to go to a window and return to the previous window.

I have done the function for going to another window.

I am having problem with returning to the previous window. I always get the error `formTrain.hide()` is not defined.

How can I resolve this error?

**Code for main window**

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from testsys_auto import Ui_testsys
from trainsys_auto import *

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def trainsys(self):
     self.trainwin = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     self.ui = Ui_trainsys()
     self.ui.setupUi(self.trainwin)
     formMain.hide()
     self.trainwin.show()
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(405, 307)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 120, 160, 107))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.btn_TrainSys = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.btn_TrainSys.setObjectName("btn_TrainSys")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.btn_TrainSys)
        self.btn_TrainSys.clicked.connect(self.trainsys)
def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Home Screen"))
        self.btn_TrainSys.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Train System"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Diabetic Retinopathy Detection"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 formMain = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
 ui = Ui_MainWindow()
 ui.setupUi(formMain)
 formMain.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Code for `trainsys` window**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainwindow1 import *

class Ui_trainsys(object):

   def backhome(self):
        self.backwin = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.backwin)
        formTrain.hide()
        self.backwin.show()

   def setupUi(self, trainsys):
       self.btn_Backtrain = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.btn_Backtrain.setObjectName("btn_Backtrain")

       self.btn_Backtrain.clicked.connect(self.backhome)
    def retranslateUi(self, trainsys):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        trainsys.setWindowTitle(_translate("trainsys", "Train System")
        self.btn_Backtrain.setText(_translate("trainsys", "Back to Home Screen"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("trainsys", "Train System"))



if __name__ == "__main__":
 app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 formTrain = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
 ui = Ui_trainsys()
 ui.setupUi(formTrain)
 formTrain.show()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always advisable not to modify the classes generated by Qt Designer, and if you are a beginner never modify that code. The simplest and most elegant way is to create classes that implement logic and use the design of the initial classes.

Assuming that when you created the view with Qt Designer you used the MainWindow templates, the classes that implement the logic should have the following form:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Trainsys(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_trainsys):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

The logic of going back in your case is to hide the current window and display the window, for this we create the following function:

```
def changeWindow(w1, w2):
    w1.hide()
    w2.show()
```

Then we use a lambda function to call them when you click on each button:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    trainsys = Trainsys()

    main.btn_TrainSys.clicked.connect(lambda: changeWindow(main, trainsys))
    trainsys.btn_Backtrain.clicked.connect(lambda: changeWindow(trainsys, main))

    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*Note:* if you have modified these classes you only have to generate the returns using the .ui file with the help of pyuic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it better for me to create a separate python file where in  I will just import the classes for my mainwindow and trainsys that have been produced by the Qt designer? and I will place the first set of code that you provided?

Comment: For a better way to sort the code is better, just import the designs, ie the UI_xxx, and then copy all the code I have proposed.